# Strange values added to the list

Tags: c, list

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


struct a
{
    a * next;
    double v;
};


void add(struct a* list,double d)
{
    if(!list->next) goto exception; //I know that a lot of programmers have a low opinion about "goto"

    list=list->next;

    list->v=d;

    return;

exception:
    printf("Cannot add a new element to the list\n");
}

int main()
{
    struct a l;
    double j;
    int i;

    for(j=1.0; j<10.0; j+=1.0)
    {   
        l.next= (a*)malloc(sizeof(a));
        add(&l,j);
        printf("%lf ",l.v);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This program compiles , but there is a mess in the output:

> -92559631349317831000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000 -92559631
>   349317831000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000 -92559631349317831
>   000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000 -92559631349317831000000000
>   000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000 -92559631349317831000000000000000000
>   000000000000000000000000000.000000 -92559631349317831000000000000000000000000000
>   000000000000000000.000000 -92559631349317831000000000000000000000000000000000000
>   000000000.000000 -92559631349317831000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>   .000000 -92559631349317831000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000

Whereas desired is:

1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0

Where is the mistake and how to fix it?

Comment: I don't believe that the program compiles. Also, don't cast the result of `malloc`.

Comment: @KerrekSB, guess a C++ compiler is being used to account for missing `struct` keyword in `malloc()` and the casting of the return value from `malloc()`.

Comment: @hmjd: In that case I should recommend using `std::list<double>` :-)

Comment: I really don't see how that's better than `if (!list->next) {printf(...); return;}`

Comment: To answer the question with a hint: `list=list->next;` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: You'd improve your output by including newlines at the end of your print formats.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `l.v` in `main()` is *never* assigned a value as `add()` assigns the value to `l.next`. The assignment of `list` to `list->next` is not visible to the caller so `l` in `main()` is always the same instance of `struct a`. Meaning the `prinf()` is printing the same unitialized `double`.

Other points:

- initialize `l` correctly:

  ```
  struct a l = { NULL, 0 };
  ```
- `malloc()` memory for the `next` instance of `struct a` within `add()` and intialize all members.
- access the most recent `next` in `main()`, by returning the address of latest `struct a` from `add()` for example.
- [Don't cast the return value of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) (and use a C compiler).

Comment: Lot of problems in the code.. 
1) Problem with traversing the nodes and their elements. 
2) Memory management you malloc but dont free
3) you dont need Goto you can use if-else ladder
Try figuring it out otherwise i will help tomorrow

Comment: `The assignment of list to list->next is not visible to the caller` - why? List l is passed to the add() function by reference...

Comment: @0x6B6F77616C74, `l` in `main()` is not changed by `list = list->next` as everything in C is passed by value, including pointers. If you wanted to change what `l` was pointing to you need to make `l` a pointer and pass in the address of the pointer (so the argument type would be `struct a**`). See http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html

Comment: @hmjd  I haven't get entirely what you wrote, but I feel that I'm very close http://pastebin.com/dkpD8MAc

Comment: @0x6B6F77616C74, you need to deference `list` inside `add()`: `*list = (*list)->next;` for example.

Comment: Now I have: `Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'l' is being used without being initialized.` How to initialize it?

Comment: Where is the List.. its just a structure having one pointer to a structure which keeps getting instantiated with new memory with old one getting lost.